# How to find the shortest public transit route to take to go from one point to another

Tags: flask, leaflet, gis, openstreetmap

I'm making a web app that makes what the title says, right now I have my bus stops and routes and I know how to add them to my map as markers and polylines respectively, I can also get the users current position and add a marker where they click on the map.

Now I need to know how to return the fastest route to get from current location to the desired destination, like google maps does, and I have no clue how to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up the Dijkstra algorithm

Comment: I would suggest to load data to Postgres+PostGIS, then use PGR module to perform shortest path computation- there are different algorithms implemented like Dijkstra, A*, …. Specifically, if you want to use data from OSM, it would be much easier to load it in Postgres and use PostGIS functionalities.

Comment: you can also use open route services - to compute shortest path from their data and using their APIs: https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-py

Comment: You will have to account for schedules, not just a simple path. This is quite involved, and I'd recommend using an API that accounts for the complexity, not building (and maintaining! schedules are dynamic) your own.